# RavenDB Error connecting when trying to create indexes

Tags: ravendb

I had an issue with my server that hosts RavenDB. It was running out of hard drive space. I cleared up some space by deleting a few databases that were no longer in use (through the management portal). I then shut down the RavenDB service. I deleted the data from the "PeriodicBackup-Temp" folder in the directory for *one* of the databases, and restarted the server. When the server restarted, I was getting errors from any site that tried to connect to any of the databases (503 server error). I debugged the error, and found that it is happening when I create the document store. Specifically:

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(new CompositionContainer(new TypeCatalog(types)), docStore);
```

Now, the thing is, I haven't changed any code on these sites in a long time, and I certainly haven't changed anything to do with connecting to RavenDB or creating indexes. Here is what the error said:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

For a while, I was also getting errors in the management portal that said that whichever database I was currently looking at did not exist (which was odd, since I was looking at the documents in the document stores while it was telling me the database did not exist...)

It's now four hours later. I have noticed all of the sites except two have started working at some point. I was hoping that Raven just needed to rebuild indexes, but when I look at the databases that correspond to the sites that are still throwing the error, Raven says that there are no stale indexes.

I am using build 2750. I have been using this build for over a year if I remember correctly.

All of my sites use the exact same code base. They are hosted on different sites and connect to different databases, but other than that they are exactly the same. I'm pretty confident that this issue has something to do with the database server, and not the web server.

Right now, the sites are not getting used, so it's not a load issue. The RavenDB process isn't even using any CPU except occasionally.

Any ideas what could be causing this? I hate to just "hope" that it's going to start working in a few hours, but it's all I have at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting about 8 hours, those two sites were still unable to connect. I restarted those websites, and everything started working again. This is something I had tried earlier, so I don't know exactly what needed to complete before restarting the site had an affect. I am completely up and running again. If anyone can shed some light on why this fixed it, I'm all ears.